# Angular вызов функции из родительского scope в компоненте

Tags: angularjs, компоненты

Вот например есть обычный модуль с компонентом

```
class TestCtrl {

     funct() {
       this.message();
     }
 }

Angular.module('app', [])
 .run(function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.message = function() {
              console.log("test call!");
     }
 })
 .component('test', {
       bindings: {
           message: '&'
       },
       controller:TestCtrl
   })

<test message="message" ng-click="$ctrl.funct()"></test>
```

Не запускается при клике по элементу, нет реакции никакой, что я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Моя ошибка была в том что я использовал функцию с аргументами. Вобщем ответ банален. Для байндинга функции angular с аргументами в директиву или компонент, нужно возвращать функцию. Вот так

```
 $rootScope.message = function(arg, arg2) {
          console.log("test call!");
 };

 изменить на

    $rootScope.message = function() {
        return function(arg, arg2) {
                console.log("test call!");
        }
   };


 Тогда в html, мы выполняем ее, не передавая аргументов и тогда будет возможность делать вызов с любым множеством аргументов. 

  <test message="message()"></test>


   app.component('test', {
       bindings: {
          message: '&'
       },
      controller:function() {
         $onInit() {
              this.message(some, some2); // исполняем функцию
          }
      }
   })
```